# Mysql updating multiple rows column from another table randomly

Tags: mysql

I have some tables as below

hotel_company

| hotel_id | company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |

company_places

| id | company_id | place_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |

company

| company_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

With the above dataset as you can see in table there are only providers 1, 2, 3 whereas hote_company and company_places has some provider Ids like 5 and 6 which are not in table Note, this is a fake data and the reason the mismatch is we are importing the data from prod to lower environment and we just want the hotels to be matched with existing provider

I am trying to randomly assign one of the available providers to hotel_providers and provider_ratings keeping the id same. so the expected output will be somewhat like this

hotel_company

| hotel_id | company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |

company_places

| id | company_id | place_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |

As you can see both hotel_company and company_places are randomly assigned 3 and 2 which are from company table. Company place duplication is allowed

I know I can randomly get company_id from table like shown below

```
SELECT company_id 
FROM company  
ORDER BY RAND()
```

but am not sure how to update multiple rows in two tables replacing exactly the same value

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` report? I'm wondering if you are using MySQL 8.0 so you can use common table expressions.

Comment: @BillKarwin It is giving me 5.7.38-log

Comment: Generally yes, but in this case no as company is in separate schema/db (microservice thing). But in sql client i can still make join across schemas

Comment: Sorry I deleted my question. I was wondering if you are using foreign key constraints. Of course you cannot use foreign key constraints, since you have mismatched values. You would not be able to insert the rows with missing company_id values 5 and 6 if you were using constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I tested, it should work on MySQL 5.7:

```
update company_places p
join hotel_company h on p.company_id = h.company_id
left outer join company c on p.company_id = c.company_id
set p.company_id = @c := (select company_id from company order by rand() limit 1),
  h.company_id = @c
where c.company_id is null;
```

[DbFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Af7UZ7t7)